# etymology of "trammel / tramming" as used in metalworking

Tags: etymology

**Tramming** or **to tram in** is a technical term used in a machine shop. A simplified definition is the process of accurately aligning the workpiece, the cutting tool and the various parts of a lathe or mill so that they are all at right angles or parallel before commencing the actual machining process. If you want to see the process in action there are numerous videos on YouTube, just search for "tramming".
I have searched for the word and found various similar definitions. Some say that a trammel is an instrument for performing this alignment, but none give what I would consider a plausible derivation.
Merriam Webster suggests that it comes from the [Low German traam - a barrow](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/tramming). via "a beam" to a beam compass also known as a trammel, but I don't completely buy this as the alignment instrument is not a compass (see addendum below).
The Free Dictionary says [[Middle English tramale, a kind of net, from Old French tramail, from Late Latin trēmaculum : Latin trēs, three; see trei- in Indo-European roots + Latin macula, mesh.]](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/trammel) but I don't see how it relates to a fishing net.
Can anyone come up with a more plausible derivation?

It almost certainly does not come from **"tram"** - a public transport vehicle.

Addendum.
There is a similarity in the appearance of [one of the instruments used in tramming a milling machine](https://youtu.be/tU87cYRpyA8?t=283) and a [beam compass or trammel](https://www.drawingislamicgeometricdesigns.com/blog/beam-compasses) but it still doesn't help with the derivation.

Comment: The fishing net was one that had coarse mesh guiding the fish to fine mesh area near the centre, so has the sense of refinement of position, similar to tramming, which refines positions. But this is merely my observation, not etymology. I would be a fool to suggest this as part of the origin. It is a good question. I can find no Scandinavian roots to help. I would not dismiss "tram" the vehicle - a word associated with the notion of the exact parallelism of the rails for barrows and the like.

Comment: Etymonline has: trammel: *mid-14c., "net to catch fish" (implied in trammeller "one who fishes with a trammel net"), from Old French tramail "fine-gauged fishnet" (13c.), from Late Latin tremaculum, perhaps meaning "a net made from three layers of meshes," from Latin tri- "three"*

Comment: If the nets in question were grids, there's your answer of a parallel and perpendicular setting.

Comment: I think fishing nets may be a red herring. Whilst the comments make good points, both forms of trammel (the compass and the machinists instrument) are straight bars with two things (a point and a pen/pencil and a pair of dial gauges) attached. Not a lot of similarity to a net. My best guess to date is from a primitive barrow, a plank (or beam) with one or two wheels. Again a bit of a stretch.